# logstash parsing old logs adds timestamp and @timestamp as date now

Tags: apache, logging, logstash

hello all i am trying to parse an old apache log the output has a correct timestamp but also a @timestamp field, the @timestamp is the now date time, how can i make sure that the timestamp becomes the @timestamp for kibana/elasticsearch. 
example input:

```
172.31.21.26 - - [20/Jul/2017:22:1``0:52 +0200] "GET /mobile/getParent/NzE4MzU1ZmUtNmIwOC00N2JkLTk1YmYtNmNhZTUyZmVmNGYz HTTP/1.1" 200 452 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14G60 (4301339520)"
```

conf file:

```
input {
file {
      path=>"/home/ronald/Downloads/log/httpd/short.log"
      start_position=>"beginning"
    }
}
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" } 
    } 
}
output {
  elasticsearch{
    hosts=>"localhost"
    index=>"roha_test"
    document_type=>"demo1"
  }
  stdout{
      codec => "rubydebug"
  }
}
```

output:

```
      "request" =>"/mobile/getParent/NzE4MzU1ZmUtNmIwOC00N2JkLTk1YmYtNmNhZTUyZmVmNGYz",
      "agent" => "\"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14G60 (4301339520)\"",
       "auth" => "-",
      "ident" => "-",
       "verb" => "GET",
    "message" => "172.31.21.26 - - [20/Jul/2017:22:10:52 +0200] \"GET /mobile/getParent/NzE4MzU1ZmUtNmIwOC00N2JkLTk1YmYtNmNhZTUyZmVmNGYz HTTP/1.1\" 200 452 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14G60 (4301339520)\"",
       "path" => "/home/ronald/Downloads/log/httpd/short.log",
   "referrer" => "\"-\"",
 "@timestamp" => 2017-10-06T08:49:10.440Z,
   "response" => "200",
      "bytes" => "452",
   "clientip" => "172.31.21.26",
   "@version" => "1",
       "host" => "ronald-XPS-13-9343",
"httpversion" => "1.1",
  "timestamp" => "20/Jul/2017:22:10:52 +0200"
```

logstash version 5.6.1

Comment: Add a `date` filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to add a [`date` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) which converts the `timestamp` field to a parsed datetime object which elasticsearch understands. Something like:

```
date {
    match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
}
```